# @AfterClass and @beforeclass in testng executing twice

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, testng

Hi I am practicing  testng and I have a simple class as follows:

```
public class testclass1 {
    @Test
    public void firstMethod() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void secondMethod() {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
    @Test
    @BeforeSuite
    public void thirdMethod() {
        System.out.println("third- before suite");
    }
    @Test
    @AfterClass
    public void fourthMethod() {
        System.out.println("fourth- after class");
    }
    
}
```

On execution, the results are

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
third- before suite
first
fourth- after class
second
third- before suite
fourth- after class
```

I am confused. Why is before suite and after class method invoked twice?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: I thought that  @after class should be executed only once ?

Comment: And you want run @BeforeSuite twice?

Comment: I am currently learning how annotations work. i learnt that beforesuite and afterclass methods would execute only once. So i am not getting how this is running twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `@Test` annotation in the `@AfterClass` and `@BeforeSuite`:

```
public class testclass1 {
    @Test
    public void firstMethod() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void secondMethod() {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
    
    @BeforeSuite
    public void thirdMethod() {
        System.out.println("third- before suite");
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void fourthMethod() {
        System.out.println("fourth- after class");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
third- before suite
first
second
fourth- after class
```